# Aggregate and lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group a mongoose query and populate a few sub-documents in mongoose using $lookup but my result document arrays are returning empty.
Can anyone tell me why?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var answerSchema = new Schema({
  _user               : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  _poll               : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll', required: true },
  _question           : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
  answer              : { type : String },
  },
  { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' } 
});

mongoose.model('Answer', answerSchema);
```

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {

  index: function(req, res, next){

    Poll.findOne({_id: req.params.poll_id}, function(err, poll){
    if(err) return next(err);

    console.log(poll);

    Answer.aggregate([
        {$unwind: "$_question"},
        {$match: {_poll: poll._id}},
        {$group: {
            _id: '$_question',
        }},
        {
          $lookup : { 
            from : 'polls', 
            localField : '_poll', 
            foreignField: '_id', 
            as: 'poll' 
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup : { 
            from : 'questions', 
            localField : '_question', 
            foreignField: '_id', 
            as: 'questions'   
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup : { 
            from : 'users', 
            localField : '_user', 
            foreignField: '_id', 
            as: 'user' 
          },
        },
    ], function (err, result) {
         res.status(200).json(result);
    });

    });
  },
```

The new subdocuments are returned empty for some reason.
Please note that each answer contains the reference to ONE poll, ONE user and MANY questions.

```
[
{
_id: "57ce8927ea5a4f090774215d",
poll: [ ],
questions: [ ],
user: [ ]
}
]
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Should I be using $project instead? I heard $lookup is the new and better way. I am using mongo 3.2.0 and mongoose 4.5.8.

Comment: Github-flavored Markdown (code sections with triple backticks) do not work here. Indent code sections by four spaces instead (there's also an editor button for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongdb aggregate query is a pipeline operation. So the result of subsequent queries is passed on to the next query. For more info on Mongodb aggregate refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). The mistake you have done is that when you used the `$group` query only _id is being passed on to the next `$lookup` query. You can fix this by using the following query.

```
Answer.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$_question"},
    {$match: {_poll: poll._id}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_question',
        _poll: { $first: '$_poll'},
        _user: { $first: '$_user'},
        _question : { $first: "$_question "}
    }},
    {
      $lookup : { 
        from : 'polls', 
        localField : '_poll', 
        foreignField: '_id', 
        as: 'poll' 
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup : { 
        from : 'questions', 
        localField : '_question', 
        foreignField: '_id', 
        as: 'questions'   
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup : { 
        from : 'users', 
        localField : '_user', 
        foreignField: '_id', 
        as: 'user' 
      },
    },
], function (err, result) {
     res.status(200).json(result);
});
```